# Array not holding initialized values

Tags: c++

I've got some very simple c++ code to show the problem.  I initialize my array with values in the ctor.  But when I try to access the array in main, those values are replaced with random numbers.  Why?

```
//Example to figure out why initialization values are disappearing
#include <iostream> 

struct Struct1
{
    float array1[2];

    //ctor
    Struct1();
};

Struct1::Struct1()
{
    float array1[] = {0.2,1.3};
}

int main()
{
    Struct1 StructEx;

    std::cout<<StructEx.array1[0]<<' ';
    std::cout<<StructEx.array1[1]<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `float array1[]={0.2,1.3};` in the constructor creates a new *local* variable `array1`.

Comment: Ditch the `float` in the ctor to refer to the member variable - and prefer using the initialization list over the ctor body when you can.

Comment: How did this get 4 upvotes? :o No offence to the OP, but this is somewhat basic.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it may be basic, but it is a clearly stated question with a minimal example program. I think that deserves an upvote compared to most of the crap questions we get.

Answer (score 6):

As @crashmstr mentioned, you do not initialise the member of the structure, but a local variable. The following code should work:

```
struct Struct1
{
    float array1[2];
    //ctor
    Struct1();
};

Struct1::Struct1()
:   array1  ({0.2,1.3})
{
}

int main()
{
    Struct1 StructEx;

    std::cout<<StructEx.array1[0]<<' ';
    std::cout<<StructEx.array1[1]<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In this case, I say, initialize in-place. There is no need to provide a constructor for this.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the local use of "float" in the ctor makes it a local variable?

Answer (score 1):

Switch on the warnings (`-Wall`) when compiling, and you will see

- `float array1[]={0.2,1.3};` is unused
- `StructEx.array1[0]` and `StructEx.array1[0]` are uninitialized

In the constructor put this

```
array1[0]=0.2;
array1[1]=1.3;
```

Comment: ChrisB's answer is also correct (and maybe nicer in this case).

Comment: That looks super useful.  Thanks

Comment: You might ask this as a new question if that is not asked yet. The answers are likely to be much better than I would guess. I am not very acquainted with make files unfortunately.